# contour integration - ML inequality

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration

I'm trying to show that $$\int_{|z|=r} \frac{\log z}{1+z^2} \ dz $$ goes to 0, as im taking $r \to 0 $

by the ML inequality $$\left| \int_{|z|=r} \frac{\log z}{1+z^2} \ dz \right| \leq \pi r \max |f(z)| $$ where $f(z)$ is the integrand in the first integral. My question is, since I'm taking $r \to 0$, do i have to calculate what $\max |f(z)| $ is to show that the integral is in fact 0?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not need to calculate it exactly. It is enough to have an upper bound. If $|z|=r>0$ then
$$
\Bigl|\frac{\log z}{1+z^2}\Bigr|\le\frac{|\log r|+\pi}{1-r^2}.
$$

Comment: how did you get the numerator?

Comment: What is the definition of $\log z$?

Comment: Small aside remark: that is for the principal branch of the logarithm. But for any branch, there is a constant such that $\frac{\lvert\log r\rvert + K}{1-r^2}$ is a bound.

Comment: I'm using the principle branch, so $logz = log|z| + i arg(z)$, but here u have $ |log(r)|$ which is by the triangle inequality im assuming but, we take r to 0, what is $log(0)$?

Comment: What is $\lim_{r\to0}r\log r$?